# How to reference font name in Next.js 13 - experimental app folder structure

Tags: next.js

Loading two google fonts to layout.js like so:

```
import 'normalize.css/normalize.css'
import Navigation from '../components/navigation'
import Footer from '../components/footer'

import { Oswald , Comfortaa} from 'next/font/google';
import './globals.css'

const oswald = Oswald({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  display: "fallback"
  
})

const comfortaa = Comfortaa({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  display: "fallback"

})


export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" >
      <body className={`${comfortaa.className} ${oswald.className}`} > 
        <Navigation></Navigation>
        {children}
        <Footer></Footer>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

How can I access font names in global.css file ?

I can see both fonts loaded under Aplication -> Frames -> Fonts

Also first font is applied to all text , but how can I apply second to H tags?

Im not using Tailwind.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `variable` field on the next/font object to expose the fonts to css via [css-variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/font#css-variables):

In `layout.tsx`:

```
const oswald = Oswald({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  display: "fallback"
  variable: '--oswald-font',
})

...
 <html className={`${comfortaa.variable} ${oswald.variable}`}>
...
```

Then in `globals.css`:

```css
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4,
  h5,
  h6 {
    font-family: var(--oswald-font), serif;
  }
  * {
    font-family: var(--comfortaa-font), sans-serif;
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response, global.css do not pick up variables. I can see two classes attached to body `class="__className_88ea5a __className_e8c924"`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response; global.css do not pick up variables. I can see two classes attached to body `class="__className_88ea5a __className_e8c924"`. However, something is happening as the first font is applied; most of the tutorials/ solutions found on the internet refer to using only one google font that is applied automatically once attached to the body; you don't need even refer to it in CSS. As chrome resolves google fonts, I have tested that on a mobile device over a local network, and the result is the same.

Comment: Found in docs:  "To use the font in all your pages, add it to _app.js file under /pages as shown below:" -- there is no nothing that would give instructions on how to use it with new /app folder that is still in beta to be fair.

Comment: The way that next does these fonts is not like any of the other Google font implementations you may see. Rather than loading it in via a link and then applying it to the body, you can either apply a single font using the classname field as in your question, or you can load multiple fonts into the root via variables and then use the variables supplied throughout css to apply that style to the components you want.

Comment: See the linked docs in my answer: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/font#css-variables

Comment: Hi Luke, I did exactly that, have loaded one font to a layout that is used globally and the second one is being set as const and applied to certain dom elements with `style={oswald.style}`, however, it seems to me be very inefficient implementation and I used it as a temporary fix until I will find a better way to do it.  I would rather control all H tags style in one place than set it as a const in every page. Unless there is a way to set it in main layout and pass it to all children's pages?

Comment: @Fengler, please read the answer, and the linked tutorial.
You use the layout-root classname to pass the fonts from js to css via a variable, and then in css-land you can assign that font to any class or element you want, via the css variables.

Answer (score 0):

In the new experimental setup NextJs with /app folder, layout.js is the place to set up font variables and pass them to the global.css file. Current docs instruct us to place it in pages/index.js.

```
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  variable: '--font-inter',
})
```

Do not use `<main className={Inter.className}>`

Use `<main className={Inter.variable}>`

And access that font in global styles via

```
.text {
  font-family: var(--inter-font);
}
```

Thank you Luke, for your help.

Answer (score -1):

There is another good way to call your fonts from google font in nextjs. This is what I do now and I've never saw a easiest practice.

1. Create a _document.tsx file at the same place as your _app.tsx file
2. Put this inside by remplacing by your fonts :

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

export default function Document() {
    return (
        <Html>
            <Head>
                <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
                <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="your google font"/>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="your google font" />

            </Head>
            <body>
                <Main />
                <NextScript />
            </body>
        </Html>
    );
}
```

And after you can normally call your fonts in your css file :

```
.my-class { 
    font-family: "my-font", sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, this is the experimental setup of Next13, and I want to use next/font method that supposes to improve web vitals.